# How to make a Typescript variable reference a class

Tags: javascript, typescript, intellij-idea

```
import { lazyInject } from './services/container';

class Main implements Main {
    @lazyInject("HighlightService")
    private highlight_service;

    constructor() {
        this.highlight_service.init();
    }
}

new Main();
```

I'm using a dependency injection package for typescript, and now my code completion on webstorm is messed up, the IDE even thinks all classes are unused since the reference is lost.

is there a way to point a variable to a class?
lets say something like

```
/**
* @Class: "whatever class"
*/
@Injectionstuff
private whatever_service;
```

Comment: does declaring that `private whatever_service : Main;` help? I must confess, I've not that much experience with TypeScript and tooling around it to know but that's how you'd normally say this variable is of this type. Not sure if that would satisfy the analysis tool, though. If it helps, even in Java some tooling has problems with dependency injection and realising something is used or not. It's a wide spread problem.

Comment: In Type script typically you specify the type information to a variable by suffixing it with `:` followed by type name. So, in your case it should be `private highlight_service:HighlightService;` or from your example `private whatever_service:whatever_class;`

Comment: If you prefer jsDoc style, typescript supports the tags specified @ https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/JsDoc-support-in-JavaScript

Comment: If I use the syntax private whatever_service:whatever_class, then I would have to import the class itself just to make autocomplete available, which takes away the flexibility of dependency inejction in this case, the purpose of the service container is to have all the classes available in advance.